# ContentProvider: bulkInsert vs applyBatch

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, android-contentprovider

I need some comparison of when to use bulkInsert() and applyBatch() ?

What are the crucial differences and typical usage scenarios?

Comment: isn't it obvious? bulkInsert makes inserts, applyBatch can do insert, update, delete ... *typical usage scenarios* if ContentProvider overrides those methods - then it should be faster(in theory fx if internal implemetation use transactions, etc..) ... if not - (standard implementation) it just iterates and call "single" function for this

Comment: Yeah but using bulkInsert() and applyBatch() also for insert